# Docker daemon cannot be started for some (hidden) reason

Tags: docker

I am trying to push a docker image and noticed that my docker daemon actually is probably not running.

If for example I run:

```
docker run hello-world
```

> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

If I try to restart the daemon using:

```
systemctl start docker
```

> Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe"
> for details.

Continuing running:

```
systemctl status docker.service
```

> docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor
> preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2021-05-12 14:45:09
> EEST; 43s ago
> Docs: https://docs.docker.com
> Process: 4810 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
> --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Main PID: 4810 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> May 12 14:45:07 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered
> failed state.
> May 12 14:45:07 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off
> time over, scheduling restart.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application
> Container Engine.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request
> repeated too quickly.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application
> Container Engine.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered
> failed state.
> May 12 14:45:09 iti-554 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result
> 'start-limit-hit'.

which as I understand it it means docker daemon is not loaded (it's in a *failed state*) and the last reason for this is the *start-limit-hit* has been reached. This on this side probably means another reason exists for this to happen.

SO, how do I find out which is the actual reason for my docker daemon refusing to start?

If I run to reset the failed attemps counter with:

```
systemctl reset-failed docker.service
```

it return without error so I assume it succeeds. And indeed when I check the status it has become:

> Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-05-12 14:45:09 EEST; 14min ago

Of course if I run docker daemon again it fails.

Can someone provide any workaround about this issue? I even tried to invoke the commands after restarting (didn't help).

Edit

Well, to my case the problem was a rather stupid one. I had added a `daemon.json` file with minimal content in it. Just this:
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
"insecure-registries": [
"docker-server.com:10022",
"docker-server.com:10023"
],
}
```

The problem was that the dangling comma before `}` made docker search for another parameter. The relevant message shown using `journalctl -u docker` was:

> unable to configure the Docker daemon with file
> /etc/docker/daemon.json: invalid character '}' looking for beginning
> of object key string

is quite obvious but the previous ones did not help much.

Comment: `journalctl -u docker` gives you docker daemon logs. Maybe u can find something there. Include the output in your question by editing it.

Comment: Thanks, @Pawel. I found my mistake. I had an dangling comma before } in daemon.json. If you can post an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`journalctl -u docker` gives you docker daemon logs. Maybe u can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

The `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` requires the correct permission to work. This a security feature for Docker.

Try `sudo chmod 755 /var/run/docker.sock` and re-run Docker command.

Note the permission number given here may not be suitable for everyone.